# protractor wait on condition should not fail after timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

Is it possible to wait on a `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf` without getting a failure if the element has not become visible? I want to handle a situation, where a button **might** has become visible through an animation and click it away.

```
browser.wait(conditions.visibilityOf(button), 500).then(function (visible) {
    if (visible) {
        return button.click().then(function () {/*...*/});
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't just you use `browser.wait(500)` ? It will wait 500ms, then execute whatever is after it, regardless of the visibility of the element. You can then try to select the element or check its visibility.

Comment: @JeremyThille Possible, but it will always wait 500ms, even if the button is visible after 1ms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out, that I can handle the rejected promise returned by `wait` to suppress the timeout error:

```
browser.wait(conditions.visibilityOf(button), 500).then(function () {
    // It is visible
    return button.click().then(function () {/*...*/});    

}, function() {
    // It is not visible
    if (shouldExpectVisibility) {
        // If I want to fail, I could reject again
        return protractor.promise.rejected('No such button');
    }
    else {
        // If I don't want to fail, I do nothing  
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  Helped solve the same issue I was having today!